# Is there a way to get inserted key and value by index in Rust HashMaps?

Tags: rust

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;


 fn main() {
    let mut map: HashMap<char, u64> = HashMap::new();
     map.insert('a', 1);
     map.insert('c', 2);
     map.insert('b', 3);

    // How can I get char 'c' and value 2 since its the second value added to the map

 }
```

I tried getting the keys and values from the hashmap and but they are not returned in right order in which they are added.

Comment: Hello, many people here watch the C++ tag, expecting questions about C++. I'm interested to know why you have tagged a Rust question as C++. What do you hope to achieve by that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a map by order of insertion?](/q/30243100/2189130) Rust's `HashMap` does not preserve insertion order; you would need something like [the indexmap crate](https://github.com/bluss/indexmap) for that.

Answer (score 1):

Rust's HashMap doesn't maintain the order of insertion. You can use [indexmap](https://docs.rs/crate/indexmap/latest) crate to do this. You can use the [IndexMap::get_full](https://docs.rs/indexmap/latest/indexmap/map/struct.IndexMap.html#method.get_full) method to get the key, the value, and the index of that key.

Comment: I think [`get_index`](https://docs.rs/indexmap/latest/indexmap/map/struct.IndexMap.html#method.get_index) is what would actually help OP. They want to get the item inserted second, so they would call `get_index(1)`. It would also be worth pointing out that using the `remove` method no longer causes the indexes to reflect insertion order.